# Matlab not plotting function interval

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the following mathemathical function:

[image: function]

I tried using the following code:

```
x= -3:0.1:3;
x1 = x(x>2 & x<2);
x2 = x(x==2)
y1 = (x1)+1
y2 = 2
plot([x1 x2], [y1 y2])
```

Why is it giving me an empty window?

Comment: `x` can't possibly be greater and less than 2 so `x1` is empty. `x2` is simply the point `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for the following conditional to ever be true since any number can't be simultaneously greater than and less than 2

```
x > 2 & x < 2
```

As a result, `x1` is an empty vector and `x2` is just going to be `2`, so your plotting command will just yield a single point at (2,2).

You want to use a logical *or* (`|`) instead

```
x1 = x(x > 2 | x < 2);
```

Also a better way to plot this would be the following

```
y = x + 1;          % Set all values to x + 1
y(x == 2) = 2;      % Replace those that meet your criteria

plot(x, y)
```

As a side note, it's generally a bad idea to use `==` to compare floating point numbers. You should instead use `eps` to check if two floating point numbers are equal:

```
y(abs(x - 2) < eps) = 2;
```